# Cannot log in to Drupal site after moving

Tags: users, redirection

I just moved my Drupal 7 based site from the computer I built it on to the Ubuntu webserver which it will run on. Everything works out fine, except for the fact that I cannot log in.

Whenever I try logging in, the site refreshes with a new URL:
`<serverIP>/node/90?destination=node/90`

But I'm still not logged in. Why is this happening?

I have enabled Clean-URL.
I moved the site following these instructions: [LINK](https://drupal.org/node/773350#comment-2866158)

Comment: This is usually an environment issue that can be resolved quickly by addressing permission / cache issues. Have you cleared cache? Do you have drush installed? If you have drush installed you can review your watchdog logs for any errors without logging in. Otherwise, are there other errors in your server logs you can share?

Comment: No I don't have Drush installed. I checked the permissions and www-data, the user running the apache service has full rights on the entire /var/www folder of the server. The apache logs don't show any errors from the last 2 hours. Before then I had a small problem because clean-url was not enabled. What cache are you refering too

Comment: drupal cache. can you install drush? that would make your life easier over the long-run. from drush you can 'drush cc all' to make sure your drupal database doesn't have an environmental variable cached from your old environment.

Comment: the problem ist, how can I install drush without being logged in as the Administrative user in Drupal?

Comment: Ok, installed Drush, ran `drush cc all` no change :(

Comment: can you share the ip address of the site you are working on? This is becoming more of a support issue than a generalized question and if you want assistance you're going to either need to provide more specifics or allow the devs here to see for themselves.

Comment: Its not an online site. Its for displaying Benchmark scores and how-tos as part of the intranet